# Run selenium tests on Windows RT

Tags: selenium, webdriver, windows-rt

we try to test a webapp in a selenium grid on many different mobile devices and desktop browsers. It works fine for android and desktop brwosers. One requirement is to run the tests on Windows RT devices (on IE). I cannot try it because I have no Windows RT device available at the moment. So I decided to google, how to do it. On my research in the internet I found- nothing. Is it even possible to run selenium tests on Windows RT? Does someone has experiences with webtesting on Windows RT?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com). [Here](http://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=live) is the list of browsers/devices supported by browserstack

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately browserstack does not support Windows RT.